# Join CSV data with an Excel file on matching column values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, database, csv

I have a file "MTN.xlsx" that I got from a database (I think), and a csv file exported by the result of an sql request.
In the cvs file each 'code' column has one 'id' so every row has a unique 'id' value.
The "MTN.xlsx" file has 48 columns. I focus on the two last one. [Image snippet of "MTN.xlsx"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlmvC.png). The values of the 47th column named 'site', has many duplicate values, which all match to a single row in the 'code' column of the csv file. Using these matching columns, I want to fill the 'siteId' column, of "MTN.xlsx" with the corresponding values from 'id' of the csv file [Image snippet of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7EVh.png).

Please, can you help me find a way to automate this matching. Sorry if my English isn't very good. Feel free to ask for further details. Thank you.

Edit: I have this Excel [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFEZx.png) and this CSV [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXQGU.png). I'm looking for a way to merge them to get this resulting excel file [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA9d8.png) (keeping all columns & rows from the original.

Something like this (written in pseudo code):

```
excel_file['siteId'] = (excel_file['site'] converted to csv_file['id'] based on matches with csv_file['code'])
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited my code to reflect the changes you require, from the photos provided. I realised I had few things backwards with my old code, hopefully this provides you with what you're looking for, if not feel free to let me know what needs to be changed with it:

```
#Read in Excel/CSV files
excel_file = pd.read_excel('MTN.xlsx')
csv_file = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv') #Change name to your csv file name

#Join files together base on the ID's given by the 'site' and 'code' columns
merged_file = excel_file.merge(csv_file, left_on='site', right_on='code', how='left')
#Assign merged_file 'id' column to the original csv file's column 'siteId'
excel_file['siteId'] = merged_file['id']


#Saving the excel
excel_file.to_excel('MTN_Updated.xlsx', index=False)
print(excel_file)
```

This code essentially combines both files on the 'site' - 'code' column relationship, essentially ordering the 'id' column in the excel file to match that of the csv file, and then assigning it to the 'siteId' column of the csv file, and then saving this as a new file.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for, or if you have any questions in general!

Comment: Thank you for the anwser but this script doesn't resolve my problem. I edited my question  to be more explicit. Please look at the images.

Comment: Hi @EDjakpa, I've realised I had some things backwards in the original code snippet I sent you, I've edited my answer and I think it should work to your specifications now, let me know if it is what you're looking for, and if not, let me know in which way does it fall short, thanks!